# Creating a Hastebin Paste with Java

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

I am trying to make a java program that could I would give her a string, it would paste it to Hastebin(www.hastebin.com) and print the paste's URL to the console and this is the code I have:
Main.java(Main class):

```
public class Main {
    Hastebin hastebin;
    static String randomString = "HELLO";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Hastebin.paste((randomString)));
    }
}
```

My Hastebin.java class:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Hastebin {

public static String paste(String content){
    final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
            URI.create("https://hastebin.com/documents")
    ).POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublisher.fromString(content).build());

    final HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, 
    HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());
    final String responseContent = response.body();
    final JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseContent);
    final String key = responseJson.getString("key");
    return "https://hastebin.com/" + key;
    }
}
```

My errors:

> ```
> Error:(14, 48) java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   method fromString(java.lang.String)
> location: interface java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublisher
>
> Error:(17, 92) java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   method asString()
> location: interface java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler
>
> Error:(19, 15) java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   class JSONObject
> location: class Hastebin
>
> Error:(19, 45) java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   class JSONObject
> location: class Hastebin
> ```

I would really appreciate getting help.

Comment: That should be `ofString`, not `fromString` or `asString`.  You're also missing `JSONObject` imports.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're working with JDK-11 (the presence of non-complaining `java.net.http` package), the APIs you're using has changed to [`BodyPublishers.ofString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofString(java.lang.String)) and [`BodyHandlers.ofString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html#ofString()). You can update them in your code as:

```
final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://hastebin.com/documents"))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(content)).build();

final HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

***Note***: The APIs were changed to what they were initially designed as during the incubator module in Java9, hence you might find documentation around with the previous syntaxes.

***Additionally***: Here is a [sample for POST](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html#post) request from openjdk.

---

Further, as mentioned in the [GET JSON](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html#jsonGet) sample, if you want to read the response as a custom object, you can use a custom object mapper as:

```
class UncheckedObjectMapper extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    Map<String, String> readValue(String content) {
        try {
            return this.readValue(content, new com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference() {
            });
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new CompletionException(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

and then read your response as

```
final HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
Map<String, String> mappedResponse = new UncheckedObjectMapper().readValue(response.body());
```

For the above fully qualified class names to resolve, you would need dependencies over [`jackson-databind`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/bundle) and [`jackson-core`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.7/bundle) artifacts.

***Note***: You can make use of the `readValue` in a more generic implementation to return custom object type.

Comment: ... and for `JSONObject` you would have to make sure that **Jackson library** is added   to your project dependency.

Comment: I don't know where should I download Jackson from, do you have a link for me?

Comment: @TalMoshel One possible link could be maven central - https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/bundle

Comment: What is it? I checked the website but I don't understand anything.

Comment: @TalMoshel Its a repository of dependencies. You can check the download option adn download the `jar` and include that as an external dependency in your project.

Comment: I have downloaded it and setten it as an external dependency but I still cannot import JSONObject. any help?

Comment: @TalMoshel have updated the answer with the code to convert the string body to a `Map` for example and provided links to dependencies required for the code.